# Getting URLs from a list to pass to HTTPGet to make an http request

Tags: java, asynchronous, http-get

Question guys.

I'm reading an information from the database and then out of it I construct a Url. I then save the Url to an array list.

The reason I'm doing this is to do an asynchronus http call.

Below code is how I create the List:

ArrayList TheList = new ArrayList();

```
    try {        

        Connection conn = getConnection();
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet srs = st.executeQuery("select distinct top 100 a.somename from sometable");

        String urlbuild = "";
        while (srs.next()) {
            Columna cola = new Columna();

            cola.setcola(srs.getString("somename "));


            urlbuild = "http://xxxx:8080/xxxx/select?q=Names:" + '"' +  java.net.URLEncoder.encode(srs.getString("somename "),"UTF-8") + '"' + "&wt=json&fl=id,colb,colc&start=0&rows=10000000";

            cola.setcola(urlbuild);

            TheList.add(cola);
        }
```

Below is the code where I try to reference the list to make an httpcall

```
public static void callhttp(List<Somename> TheList) throws Exception {
            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(3000)
                .setConnectTimeout(3000).build();
            CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();
            try {
                httpclient.start();
                /*final HttpGet[] requests = new HttpGet[] {
                        new HttpGet("http://www.apache.org/"),
                        new HttpGet("https://www.verisign.com/"),
                        new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/")
                };*/
                //final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(requests.length);
                final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(Thelist.size());

                //for (final HttpGet request: requests) {
                for (final HttpGet request : Thelist) {
                    httpclient.execute(request, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
```

However, Eclipse is highlighting the "TheList" with error of type mismatch: cannot convert from element type TheList to httpget.

This is the line in question
**for (final HttpGet request : Thelist) {**

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void callhttp(List<Somename> TheList) throws Exception {
```

This first line in your method describes `TheList` as a list of type `Somename`.  But in the for loop you try to use `TheList` as a list of type `HttpGet`.

```
for (final HttpGet request : Thelist) {
```

Change the first line of the method to:

```
public static void callhttp(List<HttpGet> TheList) throws Exception {
```

or

```
public static void callhttp(List<? extends HttpGet> TheList) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Thanks. That solve the issue I have. However, since the list was defined as ArrayList TheList = new ArrayList()., the issue is branching out to the method of callHttp(list<Httpget>) is not applicable for the arguments Arraylist(Somename) error.

Comment: Ok. Looks like I need to build or use some URI builder to save the list direct to an http list.

Comment: can you create your list as an HttpGet list?  List<HttpGet> TheList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Yup. Did that and it got resolved thanks. As usual, a different issue has come out.

Comment: Let me know if I can help with the new issue?

Comment: Thanks @Jose Martinez. The issue was about "invalid character at index... " when i tried to save the string url to the Httpget list. I've resolved the issue and found " as the culprit. Everything is working now